# show an image on Image view tool by choose

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with Image view in android studio , the Image is exist in drawable folder but is not available to choose by Image view and the extension is "png" , any helpful solutions .

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: What do you mean by ' but is not available to choose by Image view'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi probably your image name contains Uppercases or symbols(only '_' is permited in names).

If this is not your case, remember to place the image in the following way `android:src="@drawable/my_happy_image` or programatically

```
ImageView myImageView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.my_happy_image));
```